# Why does fdisk insist on starting the first partition at sector 65535 (MiB 31.9995...)

Tags: partition, ssd, fdisk

So, I have one of these newfangled external Samsung T3 USB SSD drives here, sized at 250 GB.

Let's see what `fdisk` has to say about that:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 232.9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 33553920 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x7df0da81

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *       64 488392128 488392065 232.9G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Sectors are still 512 byte large (I suspect underneath the software layer, things are a bit different), the minimum I/O size is 1 sector, the optimal I/O size is 3553920 byte = 65535 sectors ≈ 31.995 MiB

We see that the factory-performed formatting consists in a single partition from block 64 to block 488392128, which is ~232.88 GiB or ~244.19 GB.

So I just want to repartition using `fdisk`. `fdisk` insists that the first partition start at sector 65535. Maxing it out, it ends at sector 488397167, a bit further than the factory-issued partition:

```
Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1       65535 488397167 488331633 232.9G 83 Linux
```

I know about the 1 MiB alignment boundary which manifests itself by `fdisk` putting the first partition at sector 2048. The reason for that seems to be a historical accident due to a wart present in the [Logical Disk Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Disk_Manager#Compatibility_problems_with_using_a_1-MiB_alignment_boundary) of Microsoft Vista.

But what about this new 65535 sector "alignment"?

Comment: Keep in mind that the very first byte is at sector 0 according to fdisk.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I did. Thus the alignment is at "65535 sectors" (sectors 0.. 65534 are before the first partition). That number is not a power of two, nor a multiple of the old "63 sectors per track", but it seems to just be "1 element of optimal I/O size", I reckon `fdisk` just wants to optimize a bit too hard.

Answer (score 8):

If that `65535` refers to 512-byte sectors, it would not be aligned at all. Unfortunately `fdisk` with dos partitions can get funny ideas about drive geometry.

Ignore whatever `fdisk` is trying to do, just use `1MiB` alignment anyway. If you don't need dos partitions for any particular reasons, switch to gpt. If `fdisk` doesn't work, switch to `parted`, `gdisk`, or whatever works.

```
parted /dev/sdb
) unit mib    # parted uses stupid unit by default
) mklabel gpt # beats msdos by a long shot
) mkpart boot 1 512
) mkpart swap 512 2048
) mkpart root 2048 20480
) mkpart home 20480 -1
) print free  # use this whenever you want to see what's available
```